# Touchable charts library for Android

Tags: android, charts

I'm looking (since months) for a free Android chart library that handles touch for pie, bars and so on to make a drill-down of data.
Have tried many different libs (aChartEngine, chartDroid) but none of them seems to handle touch on a chart item.
I would like to avoid Html5 and web stuff, i would be interested in native charts for Android and cannot believe that there is no a lib for this.

Comment: not constructive ... SO always boring more and more...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AChartEngine can handle touch events.

The class GraphicalView has the method getCurrentSeriesAndPoint() that you can call in your OnClickListener. It tells you what item was selected.

See the Embedded chart demo (XYChartBuilder.java) from the AChartEngine Demo package for details.

Comment: Really thank you very much! I didn't know it, you helped me a lot!!